Initialize phone call from Windows 10 with paired Bluetooth android phone
I have read multiple posts suggested at the beginning of the question, but I haven't found the answer there.
I use Windows 10 Professional and have paired my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy) via Bluetooth. How can I initiate a phone call? I simply need to send the phone number. There's no need to redirect the voice or microphone to the computer. I only need to start the call, then pick up the phone and talk.
I try with Delphi (but do not limit answer to Delphi i can translate it).
I simply can connect to Bluetooth i can read all services.
={00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
={00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Headset Gateway={00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Handsfree Gateway={0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Advanced Audio Source={0000110A-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Advanced Audio Source={0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Android Network Access Point={00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Android Network User={00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
AV Remote Control Target={0000110C-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB},
OBEX Phonebook Access Server={0000112F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
SIM Access={0000112D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
SMS/MMS={00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
OBEX Object Push={00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}, 
Email Message Access={00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}

I tried with Handsfree but without sucess. I even send an AT command, like
AT+BRSF=20\r it answer +BRSF: 4079
I even tried ATD123456;\r but it every time answer ERROR.
But i suppose Handsfree is for different purposes and need to redirect voice and mic but i do not need this.
I do not know if AT commands are needed at all or there is another way to init simple phone call..
